# rosrun vs roslaunch to run a single node, any difference?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, nodes, rosrun, respawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

Well, in my understanding `launch` files are meant to launch a node or so many nodes at a time and allow setting parameters dynamically , remapping and making sure that nodes don't stop if `respawn` is set to `True` and so many other stuff.
I was wondering what is the difference between:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <launch>
      <node name="my_node" pkg="my_package" type="my_node"/>
    </launch>
```

and

```
roscore&     
rosrun my_package my_node
```

There shouldn't be any difference ?!

In my case, when using `rosrun`, my node was crashing every 30 min and no ros logs where generated but when using `roslaunch` instead, it didn't crash for hours and the log files where saved successfully.

Is it just a coincidence!? or does the `roslaunch` command run nodes in a more *coherent* way?

I would be pleased if you could explain this to me...

Thanks!

---

### Edit 1

In response to john.j.oneill 's  comment

Basically I'm running the node from a bash script, `start_my_node.sh` and I do use the `&` after the `rosrun` command, my script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#ROS exportations 
#ROS source 
roscore&  
sleep 1
rosrun my_package my_node&
```

So it is not about having a lot of text in the output?

Is using a similar script a good way to start ros nodes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273334/rosrun-vs-roslaunch-to-run-a-single-node,-any-difference?/) by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2017-10-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure how it would affect the stability of your node, but `roslaunch` does spawn each node into its own process, and then pipe the output of that node to a log file (unless you told it output=screen). Whereas `rosrun`, to my knowledge, is really just a shortcut to run the executable of your node in the terminal. This should explain why your `rosrun` generates no log files, but outputs text to the screen.

It's possible the crashing rosrun has to do with the terminal trying to keep up with a lot of text, or something along those lines. To test that you could run something like:

```
rosrun my_package my_node &
```

That will spawn it into it's own thread, and if that doesn't crash you will know it's something about the terminal causing it to die, in which case we would need to know more about what terminal emulator you are using to diagnose that problem.

---

Originally posted by [john.j.oneill](https://answers.ros.org/users/32286/john.j.oneill/) with karma: 136 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2017-10-18**:
Thanks for your answer @john.j.oneill ! I updated my question, can you please check it out?

**Comment by [john.j.oneill](https://answers.ros.org/users/32286/john.j.oneill/) on 2017-10-25**:
I don't know enough about job control to tell you whether that is the source of your problem. But there are some ways to keep track of the processes you forked off: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-s-job-control-to-manage-foreground-and-background-processes

**Comment by [john.j.oneill](https://answers.ros.org/users/32286/john.j.oneill/) on 2017-10-25**:
Also, as to whether using a script like this is a good idea, I've never seen anyone do it but I don't see why it wouldn't be fine. You may needlessly try to start another roscore if one is running, but it will shutdown cleanly on its own.

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2017-10-26**:
OK, thanks.

**Comment by [john.j.oneill](https://answers.ros.org/users/32286/john.j.oneill/) on 2017-10-26**:
If you really are just recreating the functionality of roslaunch though, I would recommend using that instead, as it provides good logging functionality and is the 'ROSsy' way of doing things. And you don't need to run roscore to run roslaunch, it will auto-start a new master roscore for you.

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2017-10-30**:
Basically, I'm using bash scripts because I kind of need to run some nodes on startup or behind some simple user interfaces. Maybe I should keep in mind that I may group the nodes in one launch file and launch them together... I will look around for the best way to do it.

**Comment by [john.j.oneill](https://answers.ros.org/users/32286/john.j.oneill/) on 2017-10-30**:
Okay. Probably better to use job control, or some other process monitor then, that way you can keep an eye on things and recover gracefully if/when nodes eventually die.